# SSRS Error - The request failed with an empty response

Tags: c#, reporting-services

We have an application running on a clients site using the WinForms reportviewer to connect to a reporting services installation on the clients server.

Since yesterday, the report viewer is throwing up the following error - 'The request failed with an empty response'.

This happens intermittently i.e. sometimes the reports open ok, sometimes they get this error in the report viewer.

We're completely at a loss as to what might be causing this, as the application has been connecting to reporting services for over a year with no issues.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar issues when implementing Report from SSRS to ASP.NET site.

The solution was configuring the Report server so that it uses also **HTTPS** in *Report Server Configuration Manager* and calling the Report in ASP.NET using that HTTPS address.

Maybe that could help also in your case.

Comment: My report is already https still get this error.